# Connectedness difference of sets

Tags: general-topology

Please help me with this proof.

If $X$ and $Y$ are connected and let $A\subseteq X$,  $B\subseteq Y$ both connected. Prove that $(X\times Y)\setminus (A\times B)$ is connected too.

I know that direct products are connected and I tried to find a contradiction but I don't know how to continue. Thank you very  much

Comment: Do you mean $A \subsetneq X,\, B \subsetneq Y$? Or that $X\setminus A,\, Y\setminus B$ are connected?

Comment: A and B are connected

Comment: @user127432 Take $X=Y=\Bbb R$, $A=\Bbb R$ and $B=\{0\}$.

Comment: You probably want $A$ and $B$ to be proper subsets of $X$ and $Y$ resp. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$, $Y$ are connected and $A$ is a proper subset of $X$ and $B$ is a proper subset of $Y$. Then $(X \times Y)\setminus(A \times B)$ is connected.

To see this, define for $x \in X\setminus A$ the set $Y_x = \{x\} \times Y$, which is a subset of $(X \times Y)\setminus(A \times B)$ (as every point has $x$ as its first coordinate so cannot be in $A \times B$) and is connected as it is homeomorphic to the connected space $Y$.

Similarly, we define, for $y \in Y \setminus B$ the set $X_y = X \times \{y\}$ which again is a subset of $(X \times Y)\setminus(A \times B)$ for the same reasons, and is connected, as $X$ is.

Now, for each pair $(x,y)$ with $x \notin A, y \notin B$, we have that the "cross" $C(x,y) = Y_x \cup X_y$ is also connected as a union of two connected subsets that intersect in $\{(x,y)\}$. Now fix $p \in X \setminus A, q \in Y \setminus B$.

Claim: $$(X \times Y)\setminus(A \times B) = \cup_{x \in X\setminus A, y \in Y \setminus B} C(x,y)$$

Proof: let $(u,v) \in (X \times Y)\setminus(A \times B)$. If both $u \notin A$ and $v \notin B$ we clearly have that $(u,v) \in C(u,v)$ and we are done. So suppose that $u \in A$ (and then $v \notin B$, clearly). Then $(u,v) \in X_v \subset C(p,v)$ and we are again done, and if on the other hand $v \in B$ (and so $u \notin A$) we have that $(u,v) \in Y_u \subset C(u,q)$ and again we are done. The other inclusion is obvious.

Also, the right hand union is connected, because if $C(x,y)$ is one of the sets in the union, we have that $C(x,y)$ and $C(p,q)$ intersect (in $(x,q)$ and $(p,y)$) so we have a union of connected sets, all of which intersect one fixed connected set $C(p,q)$. And such a union is connected by standard theorems.

So with proper subsets we need no assumptions of connectedness on $A$ or $B$. The question as posed however can have counterexamples: take $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$ and $A = \mathbb{R}$ and $B = \{0\}$, e.g.